# Hofstadter's G Sequence Recurrence in Java

Tags: java, loops, sequence, recurrence

I am building the Hofstadter's G sequence in Java using recurrence but it's not working as wanted.

The Hofstadter G sequence is defined as follows:

```
G(0)=0
G(n)= n-G(G(n-1)), n>0
```

The first few terms of this sequence are 0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5, 6, 6, 7, 8, 8, 9, 9, 10, 11, 11, 12, 12, ...

I've written the following method that is not currently working:

```java
  public static int G(int n) { 
    int i=0;
    int result = 0;

    if(n==0) return 0;

    for (i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
       result= i - G(G(i - 1));
       System.out.println(result);
    }

    return result;
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can directly implement a recursive method based on the definition:

```
public static int G(int n){
    return n == 0 ? 0 : n - G(G(n - 1));
}
```

To optimize this, you can consider using memoization.

Comment: Is there another way to implement it in a way close to my code? since I'm obliged with this format, it's for the university. Thanks

Comment: As the way I wrote it up

Comment: @FirasRihan So you have to use a loop? I am not sure what you mean because the way you wrote it does not work.

Comment: @FirasRihan What are the exact requirements for the method?

Comment: It's the way the instructor taught us, to put first the base condition ( n==0 return 0) and the a loop or an if statement

Comment: @FirasRihan So `public static int G(int n){
    if(n == 0) return 0;return n - G(G(n - 1));
}`?

Comment: @FirasRihan Because you do not need a loop for this. Please clearly describe the requirements.

Comment: I need the loop since I should print the first nth numbers of the sequence like: 0,1,1,2,3,3... or there's no need for a loop for this?

Comment: @FirasRihan Then use `for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)System.out.println(G(i));` in the main method.

Comment: it didn't work , I wrote the following :  public static int G(int n){     
int result;
    if(n == 0) return 0;
    for(int i = 0; i <= n; i++){System.out.println(G(i));}
return result= n - G(G(n - 1));
} I'm sorry for my bad coding skills

Comment: @FirasRihan Take a look at the working example here: https://ideone.com/Ie4j9G

Comment: @FirasRihan No problem.

Comment: Sure no problem

Comment: Just one more question, is it possible to implement the print inside the method so that when we call the method it prints the first 20 numbers?

Comment: @FirasRihan For that, it would be simplest to write two methods.

Comment: ohh okay it's better